# iphone 5 support for iAP2 protocol (not iPhone 5S nor iPhone 5C)

Tags: ios7, iphone-5

Could you give me some credible source which conclusively states that iPhone 5 supports iAP2 protocol?

1. iPhone 5 supports iAP2 protocol?
2. Does iPhone 5 with iOS7 support iAP2 protocol?

Thanks.

Comment: What is iAP2 protocol?

Comment: iPod Accessory Protocol version 2

Comment: What does this have to do with in-app-purchases?

Comment: I would like to find one too. But as long as all info is strictly secured and accessible only for MFi members, there won't be any source until Apple opens the technology (which is not probable, I guess). Only based on AllGo statement, that iAP has been released for the new 9-pin Lightning connector, we can assume that any device with that connector just supports the new protocol version. "Apple has redesigned the original iAP protocol to add a new version called iAP2 when it introduced the 9-pin lightning connector." http://www.allgosystems.com/ipod_accessory_protocol.php

Comment: That's not exactly true, iPod Nano 7th Generation (lightning connector) does not support iAP2.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 5 with a later version of iOS (exactly which versions, are to be confirmed) does support iAP2 protocol.

Details regarding this are confirmed when mode-switch is detected when an Apple iPhone 5 connected via BT, uses iAP2-via-BT to function as an iPod device (not just as a BT-A2DP device).